# Using EnableMenuItem on sub menu items

Tags: c, windows, winapi, user32

I have an old MFC app, and I am trying to disable menu items.

I have a menu with a typical sort of structure:

```
File
 - Open
 - Save
 - Close
Edit
 - Cut
 - Copy
 - Paste
```

Using the following command:

```
EnableMenuItem(hMenu,ID_FILE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED);
```

I can gray out menu commands of the top level menu items. However, if I do

```
EnableMenuItem(hMenu,ID_PASTE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED);
```

I cannot gray out any of the sub menu items. If I get the submenu handle and pass that to `EnableMenuItem`, it does me no good. Nor does it help if I use `SetMenuItemInfo` either

Any ideas on how to disable sub-menu items? Are there any gotchas with the EnableMenuItem function?

Answer (score 0):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647636%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need to call [DrawMenuBar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the UI to reflect changes to the menu state.

Comment: I am calling DrawMenuBar, and it works properly for top level menu items, but not sub menu items.

Comment: Maybe post more of the code then? It sounds like a problem with the way you're getting the HMENU, or perhaps you have duplicate menu item IDs.